# Why are people who haven't done anything wrong taken into custody?

Tags: psycho-pass

I watched the first two episodes, and the anime was really interesting. Why are people who have a high number on the psycho-pass shot? In episode one, the victim was shot because she had a huge number on the psycho-pass. It doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crime Coefficient is a measure of a target's probability/propensity to commit a crime. The MWPSB uses it as a measurement to determine if a target is a latent criminal or otherwise.

It is calculated and determined by the stress level (Hue), and other biological readings of a person via cymatic scan through the Sibyl System.

## Level of Crime Coefficient

- Under 100 - Suspect is not a target for enforcement action. The trigger of Dominator will be locked.
- 100 to 300 - Suspect is classified as a latent criminal and is a target for enforcement action. Dominator is set to Non-lethal Paralyzer mode. Suspect can then be knocked out using the Dominator.
- Over 300 - Suspect poses a serious threat to the society. Lethal force is authorized. Dominator will automatically switch to Lethal Eliminator. Suspect that is hit by Lethal Eliminator will bloat and explode.

[Source](http://psychopass.wikia.com/wiki/Crime_Coefficient_%28Index%29)

---

## [Make sure to check your crime coefficient!](http://en.shindanmaker.com/a/330490)

Unhappily my coefficient is of 420 so I no longer belong to this world.

Comment: I also got 420. Wonder if it's set to show the same result to everyone.

Comment: @user1306322 or perhaps we are just way over the board, but I don't think so I did with a different name and got it below 200.

Answer (score 2):

When a person's criminal rating reaches a certain point (a high number, somewhere in the range 200~400) and they are not yet considered criminal, it's still counted as "dangerous" or "very likely to become criminal soon", and so they are taken away for hospitalization and psychological treatment.

In the first episodes, a woman suffers a trauma caused by criminal actions around her. Her criminal rating spikes to a dangerously high value, at some point she even holds a weapon in her hands, which is as close to becoming a criminal as it gets. Naturally, she would fall into "dangerous, but not yet criminal" category.

Sometimes people are shot on place if the risk is too high. Sometimes a detective makes a different decision, like apprehend such a person and take them into custody, or just leave them. You should see the rest of the series to find out more on that.